# How to get WordPress menu items based on theme location as simple string/text?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show all menu and it's sub menu items form the WordPress database as simple text or string. No need to show a format. It could be object or array.

I am using this query but don't get the menu items:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * 
  FROM wp_terms AS t
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
 WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu' ", ARRAY_A  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_nav_menu to receive the menu as an array, and walk_nav_menu_tree for a string.
All the db work is already done by WordPress, thus it is trusted to work also with future and past WP versions.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/walk_nav_menu_tree/